# Call stored procedure for each item where not exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

I have the following

```
delete from Listing
where not exists
(
   select 1
   from ComparitiveListings
   where Listing.ListingKey = ComparitiveListings.ListingKey
 )
```

But what I really want to do is execute a stored procedure, `MySproc` for each `ListingKey` in table `LISTING` that is not found in the table `COMPARITIVELISTINGS` of column `ListingKey`.

I'm thinking there must be a way with a cursor, but I'm not sure? Anyone on this one?

Comment: Sorry, specific to Microsoft SQL, latest

Answer (score 1):

```
Create proc myProc
As
BEGIN
delete from Listing
    where ListingKey not in
    (
       select ListingKey
       from ComparitiveListings

     )
END
```

Comment: Where's the MySproc stored procedure call?